# MariaDB: error 1064 using COUNT(*) OVER()

Tags: count, mariadb

I have a working MySQL query that looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS nrows 
FROM warehouse_entries we
LEFT JOIN registry_entities sup ON we.supplier_id=sup.id 
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.id=we.invoice_id
[...]
GROUP BY we.id
```

Trying it in MariaDB, I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() as nrows
```

I looked at documentation, tried to add some partition information as found around, but didn't get it working. Any hint?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Windowing" functions, such as `OVER(...)` are not available until MariaDB 10.2 (and MySQL 8.0).

(This is a rare case where 1064 does not point at the best spot.  It should have pointed just *before* `OVER`, but the syntax check probable saw "over" as an alias for `COUNT(*)`, which can only be followed by `,` or `FROM`, so it complained instead about `()`.)

Comment: @AndrewPaul - Let's see the query and the full text of the 1064.

Comment: I've just noticed your reply, but I haven't kept hold of the query and error.  I did resolve the problem and it was a badly written query rather than the DB not supporting the function.

I've removed my previous comment so it won't mislead any future visitors to this question.